# pyproject.toml error: I am trying to install odoo 15 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, odoo-15, pyproject.toml

I was trying to install Odoo 15 on ubuntu device. I followed the steps in this link (https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-15-on-ubuntu-2004-lts-server), but I got the above error in step 7.

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        ....
        
          raise Exception("Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version %s, located in %r.  When we import the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version %s, located in %r.  The two versions should be equal; check your installation." % (
      Exception: Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version 1.15.1, located in '/tmp/pip-build-env-h8733xw3/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cffi/api.py'.  When we import the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version 1.15.0, located in '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'.  The two versions should be equal; check your installation.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

before step 7
run this  :
pip install --upgrade cffi=1.15

and then do step 7 but with odoo user , not with sudo